# Installing on a drive with multiple NTFS primary partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I'm currently running Windows 10 on my laptop. I have two primary partitions (excluding the Recovery and EFI partitions). I have my Windows installed on one partition (C:/) and use the other partition (D:/) generally for storing data. I'm planning on installing Ubuntu 16.04 but was wondering if it would be better to create a free space in the middle of the existing partitions C:/ and D:/ or at the end? (I should also mention that I'd like to access the D:/ partition in Ubuntu, too.)

Also, would **"Install alongside Windows"** work just as fine for me (since I already have two NTFS partitions) or will I need to go with the **"Something else"** option?

Also, the installation tutorial by Ubuntu says to select **MBR for UEFI** in Rufus. However, my current Windows installation was done with a USB created with **GPT for UEFI**. So, should I still follow the tutorial and **MBR** or should I use **GPT**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Windows to shrink one NTFS partition and reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk. Make sure Windows fast start up is off. If you understand partitions and which you want (at least / (root) as ext4) then usually better to use Something Else. You must boot installer in UEFI mode to install in UEFI mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter where to create the free space.

Install alongside Windows should work if the HDD is in GPT.

`select MBR for UEFI in Rufus` is related to creating a LiveUSB. This doesn't mean that the installed system will also use MBR.

Comment: The install was successful. Thanks. However, I have go to the boot menu and select grub otherwise it boots directly into Windows. Is this normal?

Comment: You can change boot order in BIOS.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you using following tool to create bootable USB media
[Etcher](https://etcher.io/)

What tool you are using is not important, what is important is this, you should boot into live usb with UEFI boot loader, that will ensure that right packages are installed in EFI partition of your GPT partition table and grub UEFI packages will not fail to install. When selecting boot device to boot from live USB, remember to select UEFI mode.